# OpenShift with Tomcat and PHP

Tags: php, tomcat, openshift

I have successfully set up a OpenShift application using Tomcat 7.

I have successfully set up a OpenShift application using PHP5.4.

But my objective is a web application that uses Tomcat (Java) but also serves a few PHP pages.

Is it possible to do this?

That is, an OpenShift application that uses both Tomcat 7 and PHP 5.4?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that is not possible unless you do a custom install and have an apache/nginx proxy in front of your java server, and have it take care of the php pages, and then forward java requests on to the other server.

Comment: It's a simple question. I think I may not have worded it clearly enough. I want ONE OpenShift application that is capable of running a Tomcat based Java webapp AND be able to serve a few 'static PHP pages' through Apache. This really is a simple set up. Apache serving .php and Tomcat serving whatever is in web.xml. It requires a simple answer...

Comment: The simplest answer to your question is, use html files instead of "static php files" whatever those are.  Otherwise, there is no simple setup, or pre-defined setup that will do what you want.

Comment: Tomcat and PHP are separate systems. OpenShift runs Apache web server. Apache will handle .php pages and Tomcat will handle pages as defined in web.xml. I'm sorry but I don't believe that something as sophisticated as OpenShift cannot achieve this simple setup. This is a system that I have inherited. I did not write it.